# Is it required to call context.beginPath() and context.closePath() for strokeRect

Tags: html, html5-canvas

Is it necessary to have a beginPath() and closePath() for the following code ?

```
context.strokeStyle = "green";
context.strokeRect(x, y, width, height);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `strokeRect` does not add anything to path as `rect` would do. Look at it as a one-time direct operation on the context.

**"Addendum"**:

`closePath` is used to join first point in path with last point in path, or sub-path (ie. closing the path). A rectangle is already a closed sub-path. fill() (and clip()) will close the path for you, temporary. This is because filling a shape is impossible with an open path. Temporary means it is done internally only, the path stays unaltered when fill has been completed. But you need it for strokes if you intent to close the shape (path), and you need to call it before stroke() is called.

I see many call this *after* a fill/stroke has been made, which is kind of pointless - but is not really needed when doing a fill (does this start to sound confusing? :) ).

`beginPath` *clears* the path, but again, not needed for methods which does not add anything to path (strokeRect, fillRect, strokeText, fillText etc.)

Comment: " fill() (and clip()) will close the path for you, temporary". What does temporary mean?. After the "context.arc(...)" the context.fill() is called to fill the arc. Does this "temporary" mean that closePath is required after context.fill(). ?

Comment: @Talespin_Kit they close the path internally as filling/clipping is impossible with an open path - temporary means the path is unaltered when it returns. closePath is always used *before* fill()/stroke() (no point closing it after). But there is no need to call closePath at all when using fill/clip, only a concern when stroking (and perhaps as well in special cases where paths are reused).